# mapping useState dynamic object

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make inputs for dynamic object in React

sometimes the object have

command, state

or

frame, damage, way etc....

so in 'command, state' case

I need to make input form

like

```
<input value={value.command}/>
<input value={value.state}/>
```

and for 'frame, damage, way' case

```
<input value={value.frame}/>
<input value={value.damage}/>
<input value={value.way}/>
```

and manage this object array with useState in order to handle it

But I could not find how to iterate this dynamic object in React

Here is my code

```
interface TabInfoProps {
    data: TableItemProps[];
}

interface tagProperty {
    command?: string;
    frame?: string;
    damage?: string;
    way?: string;
    state?: string;
    range?: string;
    description?: string;
}


export interface TableItemProps {
    header: string;
    columns: string[];
    data: any;
    tag: { description: string; detail: string[] };
}


const Table = ({ item }: dataProps) => {
    const { header, columns, data, tag } = item;
    const intiialValue: tagProperty = tag.detail.reduce(
        (acc: any, cur) => ((acc[cur] = ''), acc),
        {}
    );
    const [value, setValue] = useState(intitialValue);
    console.log(value);
    return (
        <>
                <form>
                    <input value={value.command}/>... with iterations
                </form>

        </>
    );
};

export default Table;
```

Comment: Have you tried with `Object.values` or `Object.entries`?

Comment: @Chris I'll try it Thanks